# Error loading https request using webView on iOS9

Tags: webview, https, ios9

I need to load a `https` request using `webView`, this is my sample code

```
NSString *url = @"https://www.example.com";

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
[self.webView loadRequest:request];
```

when I use XCode 7.0, it works fine on iOS7 and iOS8, but on iOS9 it fails, here is the ATS config

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>www.example.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
            <string>TLSv1.0</string>
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

The config does not work, opening `https://www.example.com` in Safari on iOS9 fails, how can I fix it?

Comment: I've edited your post to make it clearer. However, as it currently stands it is very hard to answer. You will need to further edit your post to include what "it fails" means.

Comment: thanks, it return kCFURLErrorSecureConnectionFailed ,I think the web page has problem, because on ios9, safari also can't open the url

Comment: Did you find solution?

Answer (score 0):

the web site can open now and I did't change anything, absolute caused by the web site it self